# Show hidden NodeModules folder in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently node modules folder in vscode is hidden, I would like to show this folder in VSCode.

Is there any specific setting in vscode to achieve this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Explorer View**

If `node_modules` is hidden in your explorer view, then you probably have a pattern that's matching that directory in your settings. Go to [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), search for `files.exclude` and ensure that you haven't excluded the directory in user settings and/or workspace settings.

**Search Results**

If you want search results to include `node_modules` by default, you'll need to remove the pattern from the `search.exclude` setting. Note that `search.exclude` inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting.

If you simply want specific searches to include `node_modules`, but don't want it included by default, there's a gear icon that you can toggle in the search view (go to the search view, toggle the search details using the ... icon, click the gear icon in the "files to exclude" input field).

Answer (score 19):

To make the other answers more explicit, in order to unhide the `node_modules` contents for one project only, create a file named `.vscode/settings.json` in the project folder if it's not there yet and add these settings:

```json
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": false
    },
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": false
    }
}
```

Note that the setting under `"search.exclude"` is required to re-include these files in the search, otherwise VSCode will inherit the `"files.exclude"` patterns defined in the user settings, which probably contain a line like `"**/node_modules": true`.

If you rather wish to unhide `node_modules` for all projects, open `Preferences` > `Settings`, be sure to select the **User** setting tab rather than the **Workspace** tab,  then go to `Text Editor` > `Files` > `Exclude` and remove the line that contains `node_modules`.

Comment: Worth noting that my issue was that it **WAS** excluded in **Workspace**, not in **User**; so might be worth checking both.  :)

Answer (score 6):

In mac

Code --> Preferences --> Settings --> Features --> Exclude --> Add Pattern / Remove

Comment: in Windows: File → Preferences → Settings → Text Editor →  Files → Exclude

Answer (score 3):

If you have .vscode folder in your directory then open settings.json file in this folder and replace `"**/node_modules": true`  to `"**/node_modules": false`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite problem and clicking 'enable' here went back to excluding them. You can toggle this behavior with the settings icon.

[image: ![enter image description here]]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answers above you can also use the context menu.
If you add node_modules into your directory you can see the folder in your solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see your folder's name or pattern in `Files.Exclude` and the folder is still hiding, this could be due to the name or pattern being included in the `.gitignore` file. There is a setting named `Exclude Git Ignore` that can be turned ON to exclude those patterns in files tree.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a  `.vscode/settings.json` with

```json
{
    "files.exclude": { "**/node_modules": true }
}
```