# node_modules Is not showing In VsCode file explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

`node_modules` is not showing in file explorer of VsCode, even if I install any module it is not updating in `package.json`. But module is installing.

I tried following:

```
npm init
npm install jest --save-dev
```

It is showing the packages are installed but it was not generating `node_modules` and updating `package.json`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show hidden NodeModules folder in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429338/show-hidden-nodemodules-folder-in-vscode)

Comment: Are the modules visible outside of VS Code?